IOS Cordova App - videos not playing - IOS 16.4
We have a very old Cordova iOS app which mainly opens many PDFs and a couple of videos. All the videos and PDFs are embedded inside the build and the app mainly works offline. Users have recently started reporting issue that videos are not playing. We think this might have broken in any of the iOS updates.
OS versions : 16.4 and 17.1
Cordova version - 6
CordovaWebViewEngine - CDVWKWebViewEngine
Videos are getting opened in the native player, and it shows the thumbnail of the video, but in the video timeline it shows 00:00 (PFA the screnshot). Clicking on the 'Play' icon doesn't do anything. And there are no errors in the logs. Issue is there for all videos. Also the web version of the same application is working fine on Safari and Chrome.

I tried to add below attributes in the  tag like 'webkit-playsinline', muted etc after doing some searches, but its not helping.
<video muted playsinline controls="" autoplay id="mvideo" webkit-playsinline 
type="video/mp4" preload="metadata" style="width:100%"> 
   <source src="file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/<app-id>/<app-name>/www/videos/video/Sample.mp4"> 
 </video>

Tried removing 'file://' as I read in some article, but thats also not helping.
I have also tried adding below configs in config.xml
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />

I tried adding below configs in the plist file as well.
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need microphone access for uploading audio</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need camera access for uploading images</string>

Any suggestions on what could have gone wrong ?

Where are the files located ? Are they in the www folder / subfolder ?

As your files are located in the www folder, it should just be
<source src="videos/video/Sample.mp4">


Thanks @Eric.. Surely I will  give that a try. But since the thumbnail is coming, I though it could not be a path issue.

Actuall I'm wrong. Its not showing the thumbnail , so issue can be because of path only.  But what path are you suggesting ?I tried with below options, but not working.

